# Spring ExceptionHandler in RestController

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a controller annotated as `@RestController`, so it automatically add `@ResponseBody` to all methods annotated with `@RequestMapping`. But if I use `@ExceptionHandler` annotation and return some response:

```
@ExceptionHandler
public @ResponseBody Response someHandler(Exception ex) { ... }
```

Can I remove `@ResponseBody` from handler? And If I use `@ControllerAdvice` is  it possible to remove `@ResponseBody` annotation from it's handlers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of Spring 4.0, `@ResponseBody` annotation can also be added on the type level in which case it is *inherited and does not need to be added on the method level*. So, if you use `@ResponseBody` on *Type Level*, you do **not** need to use it on `@RequestMapping`s and `ExceptionHandler`s.

> Can I remove @ResponseBody from handler?

`@RestController` is a stereotype annotation that combines `@ResponseBody` and `@Controller`. So, Yes you can remove it since `@RestContorller` adds a `@ResponseBody` on the type level.

> And If I use @ControllerAdvice is it possible to remove @ResponseBody
>   annotation from it's handlers?

No, you can't do that here unless you add a `ResponseBody` on the type level.

In both cases, if you return an instance of `ResponseEntity` as your return value, you won't need the `ResponseBody`.